# How do I get a single document from a Firestore query within a loop

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-notifications

In my app I am running a `for` loop in my Firestore query. this query itself is meant to only return documents where the criteria of brand and location are met (String values) AND where a counter (`"deal_number"`) located in the document is > than a comparative counter in users collections (`Login.deal_number`).

So essentially, I search the user collection for the last counter number and use that as a logical check against the counter in the deal id

```
 menuref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    menuref.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("uid", userid)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, task ->

            if (task != null) {

                return@addSnapshotListener
            }

            for (document in value!!) {

                val seller_brand = document.getString("brand")!!
                val seller_location = document.getString("location")!!
                val deal_num = document.getLong("last_deal_num")!!

//Login.deal_number is a companion object

                Login.deal_number = deal_num



                Log.d("Firestore_brand", seller_brand)
                Log.d("Firestore_location", seller_location)
                Log.d("lastdealnum", "${Login.deal_number}")

                menuref.collection("Car_Deals").whereEqualTo("brand", seller_brand).whereEqualTo(seller_location, "True").whereGreaterThan("deal_number",Login.deal_number)
                    .addSnapshotListener { value, task ->

                        if (task != null) {

                            return@addSnapshotListener
                        }

                        counter_deal = 0

                        for (document in value!!) {

                            val new_deal_num = document.getLong("deal_number")!!
                            Log.d("dealnumnew", "$new_deal_num")

                            if (new_deal_num == Login.deal_number) {

                                counter_deal = counter_deal + 1
                                break
                            } else if (new_deal_num < Login.deal_number) {

                                counter_deal = counter_deal + 1
                                break

                            }
                            else if (new_deal_num > Login.deal_number && counter_deal < 1) {

                                Log.d("Tag_counter_deal","${counter_deal}")
                                Log.d("Tag_newdeal_num","${new_deal_num}")
                                Log.d("Tag_userdeal_num","${Login.deal_number}")

                                counter_deal = counter_deal + 1


                                newdealnumref =
                                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")

                                newdealnumref.document(userid)
                                    .update("last_deal_num", new_deal_num)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener {

                                    }.addOnFailureListener { e ->

                                        Log.w(
                                            "firestore_create_error",
                                            "Error writing to document",
                                            e
                                        )

                                    }

                                Log.d("newdealbrand", "$seller_brand $seller_location")
                                Log.d("newdeal", "New deal found")

                                dealCreatedNotificationChannel() // this is the android O channel creation

                                CodetoRunforNotification() // this is the code to run for the notification. generic, havent changed anything according to normal notification creation


                                with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {


                                    notify(notify_counter, builder)
                                    notify_counter++
                                }
                                counter_deal = 0
                                break


                            }


                        }

                    }
            }
        }
```

For the above, why does Firestore create multiple notifications when there should only be a single event, is it because of the way the filter does not seem to apply correctly. Is it due to the same effect as you would have with a recyclerview/listview whereby you need to clear an array do prevent duplicates that meet the criteria?

This seems to be a common trend with running a notification based on a Firestore query. Is this even possible? I have tried all sorts of breaks in the for loop but keep getting multiple hits on the same document. I tried use the `counter_deal` to limit the amount of notifications sent once the snapshot is triggered with no luck.

[image: Database 1]

[image: Database 2]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo, database images added

Comment: @AlexMamo, as the above is a query with in a query, is it an issue to have document in value!! declared in both instances? should i rename document in the "child" query? i am sure i tested this before but will try it again. to make sure